# What am i doing wrong with arrays in methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I am unsure of what i have done wrong. I am using Java, and my console is saying that it cant find the symbol getBattingAverage.batters(i). batters is an array of 15 names, at bats, and hits ex: Anthony Rizzo 54 16.

```
public double getBattingAverage()
   {
   if(atBats > 0)
   return (double) hits / (double) atBats;
  else
   return 0.0; 
   }

public double getHighestBattingAverage()
   {
      for( i = 0; i < batters.length; i++)
         {
            j = getBattingAverage.batters(i);
            if ( maxERA < j)
               maxERA = j;

   }
```

Comment: `batters` is an array not a method.

Comment: Take an introductory course to programming in java.

Comment: There are lots of problems here - too many for one SO question - but please, please get in the habit of always using braces for `if()` blocks, even if it's just one statement. You'll save yourself tons of confusion.

Comment: Where are `i` and `j` defined? Please show where all of your variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax here:

```
 j = getBattingAverage.batters(i);
```

Should either be - a method call on an array element:

```
j = batters[i].getBattingAverage();
```

or - a method call on a **list** element.

```
j = batters.get(i).getBattingAverage();
```

or - a method call using an array element

```
j = getBattingAverage(batters[i]);
```

for example.

But honestly, the *real* answer here: don't go for trial and error regarding syntax. Study books/tutorials, *learn* how those things are supposed to work.

Comment: If I may ask - you accepted and later un-accepted my answer. That is all fine; I am just wondering if that was on purpose, or by accident?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Java - will not compile.  It's not obvious from your code what you intend.

I see you defined a function getBattingAverage().  That's OK assuming that you defined atBats and hits somewhere else.  Probably as instance fields in the containing object.  Please use curly braces with `if` statements.

In your for loop in getHighestBattingAverage you treat batters as though it's an array.  Then you say `getBattingAverage.batters(i)` as though `getBattingAverage` is an object of a class which has a `batters()` method.  Where did j come from?  Where did maxERA come from?

Java has excellent documentation.  Here is the section on [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), [Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), and the [Tutorials Home](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html), and the [API Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).  This is how I taught myself Java.

You may find it helpful to use an IDE like IntelliJ because it tells you what the errors are as you're typing and gives you hints for writing better code.  Good luck learning Java!

All that said, the ideal StackOverflow question has one issue.  This looks like it's your first Java program and it looks like a good effort.  But StackOverflow is for more specific questions.  Questions like "nothing works and here's an incomplete excerpt that I need *explained*" will be closed as too broad.  In fact, I'll probably vote to close this as being not well enough formed, or really not having a single specific issue.